# Is there a useable DateTime widget for SWT?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, datetimepicker

The Nebula CDateTime is nearly unusable for entering both date and time. Is there a sensible open source alternative?

Answer (score 7):

Use `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DateTime` ...

**Source:**
http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DateTime;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;


public class SWTExample 
{
public static void main (String [] args) 
{
    Display display = new Display ();
    Shell shell = new Shell (display);
    shell.setLayout (new RowLayout ());

    DateTime calendar = new DateTime (shell, SWT.CALENDAR);
    calendar.addSelectionListener (new SelectionAdapter() {
        public void widgetSelected (SelectionEvent e) {
            System.out.println ("calendar date changed");
        }
    });

    DateTime time = new DateTime (shell, SWT.TIME);
    time.addSelectionListener (new SelectionAdapter () {
        public void widgetSelected (SelectionEvent e) {
            System.out.println ("time changed");
        }
    });

    shell.pack ();
    shell.open ();
    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
    }
    display.dispose ();
}

}
```

It is really good. Much better than nebula widget ...

Regards,

Comment: I just don't like the widget. Any other ideas?

Comment: Use `SWT.DROP_DOWN` instead of `SWT.CALENDAR`, looks much nicer!